# Azure VM Cloud - How to access Sitecore instance from local

Tags: azure, sitecore, virtual-machine

I created a virtual machine on the Microsoft Azure cloud and installed a Sitecore instance inside the VM named sctest. I added an endpoint opening port 80, but I cannot access the sitecore instance from outside the VM. Inside the VM the Sitecore instance can be accessed via http://sctest in the browser.

Is it even possible to access a Sitecore instance from outside an Azure Cloud VM? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an Azure URL for your VM, something like http://[instancename].cloudapp.net, use that URL in your browser. You can normally find this on the overview screen in the Azure Management Portal.

Also make sure your IIS site binding is configured and allows the same URL to your Sitecore instance, or don't set a hostname and allow all port 80 traffic through to the site. You'll probably have to stop the "Default Web Site" in IIS to do this.

If you have set the `hostName` attribute in your `<site>` node in config then you also need to update this value with your VM URL. With a single site still using the `website` node you shouldn't need to update anything (i.e. this attribute is not set or present).